# Solve the recurrence relation by taking the logarithm of both sides and making the substitution $b_n = \lg a_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, recurrence-relations

Solve this recurrence relation:

$$a_n = \left(\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

by taking the logarithm of both sides and making the substitution

$$b_n = \lg a_n$$

A couple years ago I took precalc and a couple years before that I took College Algebra to brush up since before then I'd been out of school for a couple of years already. So I'm extremely rusty and this first step, getting the logarithm of both sides, has me confused enough... Like how would I even get the logarithm of the left side?? and then what exactly is that "substitution" supposed to be substitut*ing*?

So log'ing both sides I get

$$\ln(a_{n}) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(a_{n-2}) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(a_{n-1})$$

Thank you Alex below but I still don't get how that translates to the substitution equation given... or how to solve for b..? Sorry... Please help me understand better...

Would b_n =

$$b_{n} = \frac{1}{2}[\ln(a_{n-2})-\ln(a_{n-1})]$$

? Then still, how to solve that...

Answer (score 1):

Remember the properties of the log function: $a \log b = \log b^a$ and $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b$. Use it to obtain the recurrence $b_n = \frac{1}{2} b_{n-2} - \frac{1}{2}b_{n-1}$. Then solve it using generating functions or difference equations.

Comment: Should RHS not be $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(b_{n-2}-b_{n-1}\right)$ ?

Comment: yeah sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea,
but have not carried it far enough.

You have to replace
*all* occurrences of
$\ln a_k$
with
$b_k$.
If you do this,
from
$\ln(a_{n}) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(a_{n-2}) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(a_{n-1})$
you will get
$b_{n} 
= \frac{1}{2}b_{n-2} - \frac{1}{2}b_{n-1}
= \frac{b_{n-2}-b_{n-1}}{2}
$.

Solve this 
and you can then get
$a_n$.